# Image type used in the Bootstrap websites header

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Just go to the following link:

http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/

Look at the big background image on the top of the page. (It is blue and purple). I looked over that page's source code. But i Couldn't find any image file of that background. So I'm curious.

Any Help ?

Comment: It looks like a `linear-gradient` .. check out the `.jumbohead` class

Comment: I didn't get it, which class exactly ?

Comment: right click with your dev. tools on the image you're referring to and look for the class named `jumbohead`

Comment: Yes i Found it. How can i create something like that. Any clues where to begin with ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/FB4aD/)

[ColorZilla](http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/) is great tool for creating `cross-browser` compatible gradients.

```
.test{
    background: #020031;
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(45deg, #020031 0%, #6d3353 100%);
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left bottom, right top, color-stop(0%,#020031), color-stop(100%,#6d3353));
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(45deg, #020031 0%,#6d3353 100%);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(45deg, #020031 0%,#6d3353 100%);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(45deg, #020031 0%,#6d3353 100%);
    background: linear-gradient(45deg, #020031 0%,#6d3353 100%);
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#020031', endColorstr='#6d3353',GradientType=1 );

    height: 400px;
    width:100%;
}
.test:after {
    content: '';
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    background: url(http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/assets/img/bs-docs-masthead-pattern.png) repeat center center;
    opacity: .4;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

They are using the combination of css3 gradient and a png image with :after psedo calss.

See the class css

```
.jumbotron {
    position: relative;
    padding: 40px 0;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
    text-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,.4), 0 0 30px rgba(0,0,0,.075);
    background: #020031;
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(45deg, #020031 0%, #6d3353 100%);
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left bottom, right top, color-stop(0%,#020031), color-stop(100%,#6d3353));
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(45deg, #020031 0%,#6d3353 100%);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(45deg, #020031 0%,#6d3353 100%);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(45deg, #020031 0%,#6d3353 100%);
    background: linear-gradient(45deg, #020031 0%,#6d3353 100%);
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#020031', endColorstr='#6d3353',GradientType=1 );
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 3px 7px rgba(0,0,0,.2), inset 0 -3px 7px rgba(0,0,0,.2);
    -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 3px 7px rgba(0,0,0,.2), inset 0 -3px 7px rgba(0,0,0,.2);
    box-shadow: inset 0 3px 7px rgba(0,0,0,.2), inset 0 -3px 7px rgba(0,0,0,.2);
}


.jumbotron:after {
    content: '';
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    background: url(../img/bs-docs-masthead-pattern.png) repeat center center;
    opacity: .4;
}
```